# Guardar cantidades en una sesión

Tags: php, html

Tengo dos archivos php donde gestiono la compra de unos artículos, no obstante, estoy atascado en un apartado, consigo realizar las compras, me calcula el pedido realizado, e incluso la cantidad comprada del articulo seleccionado. Sin embargo, no logro llegar a averiguar que hacer para que me guarde o recuerde el programa la compra de dichos artículos. Es decir, si por ejemplo, vuelvo atrás a mi index.php a seleccionar otro producto ¿Cómo me aseguro que el que ya he seleccionado con anterioridad permanezca aún allí? había pensado en realizar una nueva variable de sesión y guardar tanto el articulo, como la cantidad que se ha escogido. Dejo por aquí mi código para que veáis que es lo que llevo.

```css
<?php
*/
//INICIO DE LA SESIÓN
session_start();
$_SESSION["nombre"] = "Comprador";
if(isset($_SESSION["nombre"]))
{
    echo "<p><b><u>Bienvenido $_SESSION[nombre]</u></b></p>";
}
//SESIÓN NO INICIADA
else
{
echo "no se ha iniciado la sesión";
}

//SELECCIÓN DEL ARTICULO A COMPRAR

if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])==true) 
{
switch ($_POST['articulo']) {
case 1:
    $precio = 1.50;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Libreta";
    break;
case 2:
    $precio = 0.50;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Boligrafo";
    break;
case 3:
    $precio = 3.00;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Grapadora";
    break;
case 4:
    $precio = 0.90;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Tijera";
    break;
case 5:
    $precio = 0.20;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Carpeta";
    break;
case 6:
    $precio = 0.10;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Cartulina";
    break;
case 7:
    $precio = 5.50;
    echo "Articulo a comprar: Estuche";
    break;
default:
    $precio = 0;
    echo "ERROR: su carrito esta vacio :(";
}

//CUANTAS CANTIDADES DEL ARTICULO VA A COMPRAR
  if(isset($_POST['number']))
  {
    if(!empty($_POST['number']))
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        $number=$_POST['number'];
        echo "Cantidad a comprar: " . $number;
    }

    else
    {
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "FALLO: Debe de seleccionar cuantos comprara.";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Cancelar </a>";
    }
  }
}

//FACTURA

if (isset($precio) && isset($_POST['number']))
{
echo "<br/>";

echo "Total a pagar: " . $number * $precio . " €.";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='pedidos.php'> gestionar pedido </a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='inicio.php'> Volver </a>";
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

    

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>

<form id="inicio" method="post" action="carrito.php">
    <p>
        <select name="articulo">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Libreta - 1.50€</option> 
            <option value="2">Boligrafo - 0.50€</option> 
            <option value="3">Grapadora - 3.00€</option>
            <option value="4">Tijera - 0.90€</option> 
            <option value="5">Carpeta - 0.20€</option> 
            <option value="6">Cartulina - 0.10€</option>
            <option value="7">Estuche - 5.00€</option>
         </select>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <label for="nombre">¿Cuantos quiere comprar?</label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Añadir al carrito">
    </p>


    
    <?php
    
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución que se me ocurre es guardar los datos en cookies.

```
setcookie($nombre, $valor, $caducidad, $ruta, $dominio, $seguridad, $solohttp);
```

Por ejemplo:

```
setcookie('anterior', '1'); //se guarda la cookie con nombre 'anterior' y valor '1'
```

Y para traer el valor:

```
$anterior = $_COOKIE['anterior']; //se guarda en `$anterior` el valor de la coockie('1')
```

Las cookies se guardan hasta que se cierre el navegador a no ser que se le especifique una caducidad o se elimine con:

```
unset($_COOKIE['anterior']);
```

Esta es una solución que se me ocurre, también se podría guardar en un archivo .txt o en la base de datos, pero no creo que sean soluciones efectivas.